# Keras model not learning after training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am training a keras model for a sentence classification task. The problem is although it is giving an accuracy of 94%, it is not learning anything. When I give a new sentence (not present in the dataset), it gives the same probability for it (in the `model.prediction` step). I can't figure out why is this happening.

Here is my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

Here `max_words = 2000` and `max_len=300`

Here is the model summary

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_3 (Embedding)      (None, 300, 30)           60000     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 300, 30)           120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 64)                16128     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 64)                256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 130       
=================================================================
Total params: 76,634
Trainable params: 76,446
Non-trainable params: 188
```

And here is the code, the size of my dataset is 20k, with 10% in testing.

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')
history = model.fit(sequences_matrix, Y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=50, validation_split=0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing activation function of the last layer from sigmoid to softmax. It doesn't quite match the loss you are using (categorical cross-entropy). If you use sigmoid, then you only need one unit and should use binary cross-entropy loss.

Comment: No, even by using softmax function with categorical cross entropy, there is no difference. The probability is coming the same for whatever sentence I give.

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar Then maybe check your data? For example when you feed sentences for prediction, does the sequence matrix look right? (different token ids from different sentences, correct ids and paddings etc.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227885/keras-model-predict-giving-same-values here I have explained about the sequence matrix problem, please have a look. There seems to be some problem in tokenizer fitting.