# Keras model.predict giving same values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am using Keras `model.predict` to get label for new sentences not present in the dataset. But the prediction is always giving the same value irrespective of the sentence.

Here is my prediction code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

maxlen = 300
### PREDICT NEW UNSEEN DATA ###
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
label_enc.fit(tar_list)
X_test = ['asdsadav dawd','this is boring', 'wow i like this you did a great job', 'ima cry tht was mean','1 nov 1968 george harrison became the first beatle to release a solo album in the u k with the soundtrack to ']

X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen)

print(X_test)

a = (model.predict(X_test)>0.5).astype(int).ravel()
print(a)

reverse_pred = label_enc.inverse_transform(a.ravel())
print(reverse_pred)

print(model.predict(X_test))
```

And here is the output

```
 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
[[0.988675   0.01132498]
 [0.988675   0.01132498]
 [0.988675   0.01132498]
 [0.988675   0.01132498]
 [0.988675   0.01132498]]
```

As we can see, the probability output is same for every sentence.

My code for training model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 300, input_length=max_len))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')
```

This is the tokenizer fitting for X_train

```
max_words = 3000
max_len = 300
tok = Tokenizer(num_words = max_words)
tok.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen = max_len)
print(sequences_matrix)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
Y_test = np.array(Y_test)
```

Output is

```
[[  0   0   0 ...  11  28  33]
 [  0   0   0 ...   2 125  63]
 [  0   0   0 ...   9 184  91]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ... 105  22  85]
 [  0   0   0 ...  22  42 512]
 [  0   0   0 ...   9  28 406]]
```

Comment: what's the result of print(X_test) ? (after pad_sequences)

Comment: I've edited the question with the outout of X_test. Please have a look. They all are 0.

Comment: X_test (after padding is all 0) this means 2 things... you didn't fit tokenizer with X_train or X_test contains all unseen word not present in X_train

Comment: After `X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)` this step. The output is coming an empty list like this `[ [ ], [ ], [ ], [ ], [ ] ]`

Comment: this means 2 things... you didn't fit tokenizer with X_train or X_test contains all unseen word not present in X_train... check this 2 points

Comment: I have fitted tokenizer with X_train and also when I am using the same sentences directly from the dataset which I have used, the output is the same nothing different.

Comment: try to check tokenizer.word_counts

Comment: how do I use it? like `print(tokenizer.word_counts(X_test))`

Comment: print(tokenizer.word_counts)

Comment: Error `collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable`

Comment: is print(tokenizer.word_counts) and not print(tokenizer.word_counts())

Comment: `print(tokenizer.word_counts)` output is `OrderedDict()`

Comment: it's empty! this means you didn't fit it properly with your X_train

Comment: I have added the tokenizer fitting for X_train in the question (at last). Please have a look and see if there's some mistake.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading things too literally or if it's indeed as simple as that: it seems you created a different tokenizer on test set than the one used for training set... And the new tokenizer is not fit to any dataset, hence the empty dictionary & sequences.